# Ruby split String into two sections and put in hash with predefined keys

Tags: ruby, string, hash, split

I don't know if this is actually good ruby code, but what I am trying to do is split a String into two separate sections and put the two as values to two specific keys. For example:

```
  name_a = "Henry Fillenger".split(/\s+/,2)
  name = {:first_name => name_a[0], :last_name => name_a[1]}
```

I was wondering if this could be done in a single line through some ruby magic however.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `Hash[]` and [`zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) to do this:

```
name = Hash[ [:first_name, :last_name].zip("Henry Fillenger".split(/\s+/,2)) ]
```

However I'd say your version is more readable. Not everything has to be on one line.

Comment: Thanks, while it is true that not everything has to be in one line. The reason I asked it like that was to pretty much wonder if there was a "ruby way" to do it (I noticed ruby way always means 1 line and super easy to read). This one would work great except error checking would suck on it, but still it is the answer I was looking for. Thanks again

Answer (score 9):

Still two lines, but slightly more readable in my opinion,

```
first_name, last_name = "Henry Fillenger".split(/\s+/,2)
name = {:first_name => first_name, :last_name => last_name}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, a non-split variant (which is also two lines):

```
m    = "Henry Fillenger".match(/(?<first_name>\S+)\s+(?<last_name>\S+)/)
name = m.names.each_with_object({ }) { |name, h| h[name.to_sym] = m[name] }
```

The interesting parts would be the named capture groups (`(?<first_name>...)`) in the regex and the general hash-ification technique using [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001516). The named capture groups require 1.9 though.

If one were daring, one could monkey patch the `each_with_object` bit right into [`MatchData`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html) as, say, `to_hash`:

```
class MatchData
    def to_hash
        names.each_with_object({ }) { |name, h| h[name.to_sym] = self[name] }
    end
end
```

And then you could have your one-liner:

```
name = "Henry Fillenger".match(/(?<first_name>\S+)\s+(?<last_name>\S+)/).to_hash
```

I don't really recommend this, I only bring it up as a point of interest. I'm a little disappointed that `MatchData` doesn't have a `to_h` or `to_hash` method already, it would make a sensible complement to its [`to_a`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html#M000406) method.

Comment: First I'm using 1.9 so that is fine. This each_with_object is a really cool feature I hadn't seen before and is in a way what I was looking for. However I am confused on what it is actually doing, m is an enum where you have somehow connected the matches to the <first_name> and <last_name> and then grab that via a to_sym call?  Then you have the each_with_object which iterates over "Henry" and "Fillenger" setting those as the values inside and is defining it will return a hash with the parameter { } correct?

Comment: @Craig: `m` is a MatchData, the [`names`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html#M000400) method of MatchData returns the names of the named capture groups in the regex (`(?<xxx>...)`) as an array of strings. If you have a named capture group, `(?<x>...)`, then you can get what it matched from `m[:x]` so if `name` is a capture group name as a string then `m[name.to_sym]` is what was matched; `names` gives us strings but `m[]` wants symbols, hence the `to_sym`.